# How to calculate rotation for Mesh2 based on identical Mesh1 and its local vertices data?

Tags: python, quaternion

I have two identical meshes. Their rotation is already applied in Blender (0,0,0). I would like to restore rotation for mesh2 based on mesh1 as a reference object.

I have a python script that finds all identical meshes (with the identical geometry data) and converts them to instances. Right now, after linking mesh data, all objects are correctly located to their origin (which is the center of mass) but I lose the rotation.

The purpose of this is to align all meshes to their correct (preivous) rotation after being converted to instances.

Thank you!

Comment: So, let’s say you have two unlinked objects, a mug with the handle pointing north, and another one with the handle pointing east, with rotation applied on each. Are you saying that your script would detect that the two mugs are similar and change it so it’s the same mesh block with the handle pointing north, but now you want in the system to add an object transform that moves the one mug back to the handle pointing east, although it is now sharing the same mesh data?

Comment: @TheLabCat yes, exactly, we have scenes with hundreds of identical meshes (identical geometry data), we want to convert them to instances and (the reason of the question) to re-calculate rotation for new instance meshses. So that they have the same orientation as previously located mesh.

Comment: Communities are referencing to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kabsch_algorithm Was wondering if there is a less sophisticated geometry approach to calculating those.

Comment: OK, that makes sense. However, adding rotation to an object in blender is extremely easy in Python or in UI, so… I would think all you would need to do is find out from the geometry matching algorithm what the offset angle was. Can you do this?

Comment: Hang on… How is your script detecting that the mesh is the same? I assumed it was matching vertices with mathematics, but is it just going on a naming system?

Comment: @TheLabCat basically, taking vertex data, indices, edges, etc., and comparing them. That is what I am looking for, to find rotation offset. :)

Comment: I would think after it’s analyzed all that and discovered that the mesh matches, it would already have the rotation offset itself. If not, you could try comparing two vertices with their matching vertices and use trigonometry on the vectors between each.